# DjangoCKEditor Configuration Fully Enabled

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms, django-ckeditor

I am using `djangocms-text-ckeditor` on a couple of my sites.

On one of them, I have the following in `base.py`

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar': 'full',
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['ShowBlocks'],
        ['Format', 'Styles'],
    ],
    'skin': 'moono-lisa',
    'removePlugins': ['image'],
    'extraPlugins' : [
        # these are non-standard plugins
        'codesnippet',
        'html5audio',
        'image2',
        'autogrow',
    ],
}
```

This provides the following editor toolbar

[image]

On another site, I have not added anything into `base.py` and get this

[image]

My question is how I can get the CMSPlugins section in the first site. Also, what should a config look like if I want all plugins enabled explicitly?

Comment: Why do you want to enable plugins explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's no easy way to achieve what you need. It's certainly strange that the `'full'` option doesn't include the CMSPlugins menu. What you can do is replace the `'toolbar': 'full'` in your `CKEDITOR_SETTINGS` with an explicit toolbar configuration. If you *really* need the full set of options,
it would probably look something like this - a caveat though: I didn't test this and am not entirely sure about some of the options, so adapt this to your needs.

```py
# add to CKEDITOR_SETTINGS
'toolbar_CMS': [
    [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
    ['Undo', 'Redo'],
    ['cmsplugins', 'cmswidget'],
    ['Find', 'Replace'],
    ['SelectAll'], 
    ['Scayt'],
    ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'HiddenField'],
    ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'],
    '/',
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'], 
    ['CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat'],
    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
    ['Outdent', 'Indent'],
    ['Blockquote', 'CreateDiv'],
    ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
    ['BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language'],
    ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
    ['CodeSnippet', 'Image2'],
    ['Html5audio', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']
    '/',
    ['Styles', '-', 'Format', '-', 'Font', '-', 'FontSize'],
    ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
    ['About'],
    ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']
]
```

Also take a look at the [CKEditor Toolbar Configurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic) and the old
version of it [here](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/old/toolbar/toolbar.html) (I am quite sure Django-CMS doesn't use the latest version of CKEditor). It outputs JavaScript, but it's still very useful as an overview of the menu icons and their names.